# Can I combine the results of one tables rows into a single row (with columns)?

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I am essentially trying to accomplish this following:

### Table 1:

```
MemberID   |    selection 1     |    selection 2     |     selection 3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      |        A           |                    |                 
12345      |                    |       B            |                   
12345      |                    |                    |          C
```

Transforms into

### Table 2:

```
MemberID   |    selection 1     |    selection 2     |     selection 3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      |        A           |       B            |        C
```

Part of me thinks a 'UNION' is the way to go but this is normally reserved for columns into rows I believe.

Any ideas?

Comment: are the columns you wish to discard always empty? :O

Comment: oh, and also, will MemberID always be the same in these rows?

Comment: The result set from table 1 has 10,000 rows, if a member only has one selection, it will only show in one row, if a member has all 3 selections, a result will appear in all three columns (but in 3 rows). Table 1 is generated off another query based on a member's selections

Comment: Are there any cases where two of the columns could have values, or all three? what happens in such a case?

Comment: @Marc B - the example I show above is I think exactly what you are asking (unless you mean that "in table 1 can more than one column be populated" and if that is the case then No).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is an aggregation trick. Are the columns without data NULL or just blank? Perhaps the values sort above or below the blank columns. In that case:

SELECT MAX(column1),MAX(column2),MAX(column3) FROM table GROUP BY MemberID;

Comment: I didn't think about using MAX, without it, the group by fails and still leaves columns blank but since the result is either (value or NULL), your MAX theory works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

i'm thinking you're trying to have two responsibilities in one table. how about

table 1, members

```
id
```

table 2, selections

```
id
member_id
selection
```

data would look like this:

table 1 (members)

```
id
----
12345
```

table 2 (selections)

```
id    member_id    selection
--------------------------------
1     12345        a
2     12345        b
3     12345        c
```

then you would get all selections, one per row, by doing

```
SELECT members.id,
       selections.selection
FROM   members
JOIN   selections
ON     members.id = selections.member_id
```

or if you just want the selections of one member

```
SELECT member_id AS id,
       selection
FROM   selections
WHERE  member_id = ?
```

Comment: @devogotland - what you describe is already exactly how the tables are laid out (that is how table 1 is created).  need to combine and create my table 2 above (multiple rows) based on my start table (your table 2 then to my table 1 then to my table 2).

Comment: To clarify - I want to, in short theory, return ALL selections for a particular member in a single row where they used to be in multiple